# Passing puppeteer an internal docker network URL

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

I can get puppeteer to work fine when my page is hosted on a remote host:

```
const url = 'https://paidhost.com/app/mypage.html';
await page.goto(url);
```

I'm running this within a node.js app inside a Docker container (in a swarm) running on my own server, and deployed via [CapRover](https://caprover.com/) which does all of the legwork in setting up the docker services etc.

To remove the need for `paidhost.com`, and so that requests from puppeteer to the 'host' need not even leave my server, I thought I should just be able to serve the same content (html, js, cs, images, etc) via a second node app running on my existing server [using express static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), within the same docker swarm.

The second node app (hosting my web page) is accessible internally within the swarm via URL `http://srv-captain--mynodehost/app/mypage.html`.  By internal I mean a URL that allows requests to be sent internally over the docker network that connects containers in a swarm, like mentioned [here](https://github.com/caprover/caprover/issues/827#issuecomment-689822995) and [here](https://github.com/caprover/caprover/issues/1590#issuecomment-1345379169).

I have confirmed that the html page served by the second node app *is* accessible from the first node app over the docker network via the internal URL, because fetching the raw html page itself from the first node app (without attempting to render it) using my favourite http request library via URL `http://srv-captain--mynodehost/app/mypage.html` works fine... so it's definitely accessible "internally" via this form of URL.

I can also access this page from a public web browser which accesses this node server from the outside via `https://mynodehost.com/app/mypage.html`, and it all renders fine in the browser.

So the following "external" load works:

```
const url = 'https://mynodehost.com/app/mypage.html';
await page.goto(url);
```

But when I use the "internal" URL for a puppeteer page load from the first node app, it doesn't work (even though the page should be accessible... see above):

```
const url = 'http://srv-captain--mynodehost/app/mypage.html';
await page.goto(url);
```

It tries for a while, then just times out with `TimeoutError: Waiting failed: 20000ms exceeded`.

Using the "external" URL (pointing to my node 'host' endpoint) has one benefit... I don't have to pay for `paidhost.com` and upload content there.  But it does still mean that traffic is sent outside of the swarm, outside the server, and then comes back again.  The main benefit I want to achieve with this is reduced latency by using internal requests where possible.

So, how do I point puppeteer to the internal docker network URL, and make it work?

The Dockerfile contains the following for the puppeteer installation:

```
FROM node:18.16.0
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
     chromium \
     (various other dependencies) \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true
ENV CHROME_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

With package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "puppeteer": "^19.11.0",
  (various other dependencies)
},
```

The version of chromium running inside the container is:

```
# chromium --version
Chromium 112.0.5615.121 built on Debian 11.6, running on Debian 11.6
```

**EDIT** I have now also [posted an issue over on puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10074) and have received some very useful insight from there.

Comment: What image are you using for the node+puppeteer container?

Comment: @Matt question updated... let me know if you think more info is needed.  Thanks.